# Software to perform mathematical optimization using arbitrary precision numerics

Tags: math, optimization

I need to perform multidimensional line search and/or trust region optimization using arbitrary-precision numerical libraries such as [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/) and [GNU MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/).

Are there any already written routines that can do that today?

EDIT: due to the lack of answers, I've also asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70916207/how-can-i-perform-line-search-and-or-trust-region-optimization-using-arbitrary-p).

Comment: We employ 2 mathematicians full time to implement stuff like that for 3D only. Sorry, I doubt that a library has exactly the algorithm you need.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, oh, I see, thanks for the advice. Perhaps its then worth spending some time to build an open-source prototype based on Octave's [fminunc](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/e2c8c852399e/scripts/optimization/fminunc.m). By the way, MCOSMOS looks like a great product.

Comment: thanks. It's a product full of features and since we have done the UI refresh, it doesn't even look like 1990s any more ;-)